# How to set up gmail push notification

Tags: push-notification, gmail, gmail-api, google-cloud-pubsub

I tried to understand how [this](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push?authuser=2#getting_gmail_mailbox_updates) works since more than a day, and I'm totally confused right now.

Here is my (very simple) goal: **make a GET request on a URL when I receive a new email.**

- I have created a **topic** as they asked (named *new-email*)
- I have a **subscription** in that topic (named *new-email-inbox*), with delivery type **push**, and setting my endpoint URL.
- I gave my subscription authorization to this account: **gmail-api-push@system.gserviceaccount.com** (*Editor* & *Editor Pub/Sub*)

How do I set up the rest ? I don't understand what to do now..

Comment: The next step is using a Gmail Client and let a code running listenning to the [Users: watch](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/watch) endpoint as the [docs](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push?authuser=2#getting_gmail_mailbox_updates) say. What programming language are you using?

Comment: I use php. I did it with a cronjob, asking everyday to **watch** one endpoint. The thing is, as I need to use it all the time, I don't understand why I can't set that watch request forever the first time and i'm done with it. Or even set that up in the Google API manager by enabling it here (and disable it if needed).

Comment: you can't set it for ever because you are using the HTTP protocol when calling the endpoint, which is an stateless protocol that needs to be closed eventually. That's how REST APIs architectures work. Anyways, I'm glad you could find a workaround for your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a **Symfony4** command, executed everyday like a cron:

```
class WatchGoogleClient extends Command {

    private $kernel;
    private $gmailService;

    public function __construct(GmailService $gmailService, Kernel $kernel)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->gmailService = $gmailService;
        $this->kernel = $kernel;
    }

    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('app:watch-google-client')
            ->setDescription('watch-google-client')
            ->setHelp('Reset the google watch timer');
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        // This getClient function is basically what is given by the google API tutorial
        $client = $this->gmailService->getClient($this->kernel);
        $service = new \Google_Service_Gmail($client);
        $watchreq = new \Google_Service_Gmail_WatchRequest();
        $watchreq->setLabelIds(array('INBOX'));
        $watchreq->setTopicName('YOUR_TOPIC_NAME');
        $msg = $service->users->watch('me', $watchreq);

        var_dump($msg);
        // DO WHAT YOU WANT WITH THIS RESPONSE BUT THE WATCH REQUEST IS SET
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the reply from @antoine-nedelec I was also create a watcher in **Laravel**.

I installed the package google/apiclient (`composer require google/apiclient`)

However I to implement some **modifications**, as otherwise this did not work for me:

- Enable **domain wide delegation** for this service account: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account?hl=en#delegatingauthority (https://admin.google.com/ac/owl/domainwidedelegation?hl=de needed to use the id, and not the email and used the scope `https://mail.google.com/`) or I would have received an error `Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested.`
- **Use my email instead of "me"** (otherwise received `Precondition check failed.` error).
- I already had a **credentials** for pub/sub notifications, so I used that file
- **Enabled GMail Api** (that one was easy).

Of course this code has just `dd` for seeing an output. For production you could handle the exception and just ignore the `$messagesResponse`.

```php
<?php
    
use Google_Client;
use Google_Service_Gmail;
use Google_Service_Gmail_WatchRequest;

define('MY_EMAIL', 'myemail@example.com');
define('PROJECT', 'pivotal-destruction-123456');
define('TOPIC', 'my_topic');

function watch()
{

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfig(resource_path('mycredentials.json'));
    $client->setSubject(MY_EMAIL);
    $client->addScope("https://mail.google.com/");
    $client->setAccessType("offline");
    $client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
    $service = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);
    try {
        $watch = new Google_Service_Gmail_WatchRequest($client);
        $watch->setTopicName("projects/" . PROJECT . "/topics/" . TOPIC);
        $messagesResponse = $service->users->watch(MY_EMAIL, $watch);
    } catch(\Exception $e) {
        dd("EXCEPTION", $e);
    }

    dd("WATCHED!!!", $messagesResponse);
}
```

BTW I tried to log the output from the webhook, but first missed to **disable the CSRF check** (`VerifyCsrfToken.php`), so did not get any notifications.